# Faster alternative to preg_match while maintaining search logic

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm having a few problems with the speed of a search function I have created.

My search uses preg_match to separate keywords from a text. It can search for "Intern" but not "Internet" or "International".

But it runs really slow, is there anyway you can speed kind of function up?

```
 foreach ($keywords as $Word)
 {
   if (preg_match("/\S*\b($Word)[s]?\b\S*/i", $Text))
   {
     return $Word;
   }
 }
```

Thanks :)

Comment: By removing the first `\S*` the expression will be fast enough already. The second one is also redundant in your `preg_match`.

Comment: And `\S*` makes no sense in this context anyway.  `\S` matches any non-whitespace character, which i can't believe is what you meant, and `*` makes it optional, so it has no effect anyway (other than to slow down matching).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By removing the first `\S*` the expression will be fast enough already. The second one is also redundant in your `preg_match`.

You also need to double-escape special regex metacharacters inside a double-quoted PHP regex.

Use

```
foreach ($keywords as $Word)
 {
   if (preg_match("/\\b(" . preg_quote($Word) . ")s?\\b/i", $Text))
   {
     return $Word;
   }
 }
```

See [this IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/verxLM)

Note that if you have special characters (like `[` or `(`) inside the $keywords array, you need to use `"/(?<!\\w)(" . preg_quote($Word) . ")s?(?!\\w)/i"` regex.

Comment: Thank you, for your words of wisdom. I have tested 3 methods of speeding  up my search, and your chans have increased the speed by at least 40%.